I want to do FFT conversion and plot the results as an example, but it doesn't work
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sampling rate
dt = 0.01  # 0.01초 간격

# rpm raw data
data1 = np.array([735, 743, 744, 739, 734, 752, 750, 745, 739, 751, 751, 745, 740, 757, 755, 749, 743, 745, 748, 742, 736, 748, 747, 741, 734, 751, 752, 747, 740, 737, 734, 730, 722, 731, 737, 732, 723, 738, 747, 743, 734, 747, 751, 749, 738, 750, 759, 755, 746, 752, 757, 753, 744, 747, 756, 753, 743, 749, 754, 752, 742, 743, 750, 747, 738, 740, 745, 745, 734, 737, 746, 746,734, 747, 754, 752, 741, 746, 753, 753, 741, 745, 752, 751, 741, 749, 759, 758, 746, 754,761, 760, 748, 753, 761, 761, 750, 751, 756, 757])


# FFT
fft_result1 = np.fft.fft(data1)
fft_magnitude1 = np.abs(fft_result1)

N = len(data1)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=dt)  

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(freq, fft_magnitude1, label='Signal 1')
plt.title('FFT Result')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.xlim(4, 50)  
plt.ylim(0, 500)
plt.xticks(np.arange(4, 51, 2))  
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

It is a car's rpm signal, and I want to analyze its frequency. I want to convert it to FFT and analyze the strength of the signal for each HZ. I want to express the unit of the y-axis as [n/rpm]. Is this possible? And commercial tools have these options, but how do you apply them? resampling = 2048HZ, spectrum size = 8192, window function = Hanning, Overlap=50%, Amplitude Scaling = Peak.
x-axis is in [HZ] / y-axis is in [n/rpm]


I have no clue what n/rpm is supposed to mean but the rest sounds like Welch's method, which is available in Scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html

You are not scaling the magnitude of the FFT after calculating it. I did this example as an approximation of your desired results, I also applied a hamming window to the signal and removed the DC component before FFT:
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dt = 0.01 # sampling rate
data1 = np.array([735, 743, 744, 739, 734, 752, 750, 745, 739, 751, 751, 745,
                  740, 757, 755, 749, 743, 745, 748, 742, 736, 748, 747, 741,
                  734, 751, 752, 747, 740, 737, 734, 730, 722, 731, 737, 732,
                  723, 738, 747, 743, 734, 747, 751, 749, 738, 750, 759, 755,
                  746, 752, 757, 753, 744, 747, 756, 753, 743, 749, 754, 752,
                  742, 743, 750, 747, 738, 740, 745, 745, 734, 737, 746, 746,
                  734, 747, 754, 752, 741, 746, 753, 753, 741, 745, 752, 751,
                  741, 749, 759, 758, 746, 754, 761, 760, 748, 753, 761, 761,
                  750, 751, 756, 757]) # data
data1 = data1 - data1.mean() # removing the DC component
N = len(data1) # length of signal, this needs to be used for scaling the FFT
hammingWindow = np.hamming(N) # generate the hamming signal
data1 = data1 * hammingWindow # apply the hamming window
fft_result1 = np.fft.fft(data1) # get fft
fft_magnitude1 = np.abs(fft_result1)/N # calculate the magnitude and divide by N
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=dt) # get the frequency vector
halfMagnitude = 2*fft_magnitude1[:N//2] # get only half the magnitude, here you have the option of doubling as well
halfFrequencies = freq[:N//2] # get only half the frequencies
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6)) # figsize
plt.plot(halfFrequencies, halfMagnitude, label='Signal 1') # plotting
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)') # xlabel
plt.ylabel('Magnitude in original unit (in this case RPM)') # ylabel
plt.grid() # turn grid on
plt.xlim((16,40)) # xlim to reproduce your plot
plt.ylim((0,10)) # ylim to reproduce your plot

This is not one-to-one with your desired results, but it is pretty close. I assume the difference comes from the overlap or resampling:

